# Learning handling exceptions, can't figure out this FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

I'm a beginner still, and currently learning about handling exceptions. The exercise in my book I'm trying to figure out tells me to add a Finally block to close out the file I opened, and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Keep in mind the file name and path are fake but here is what I have:

```
public static String readLineWithFinally()
{
    System.out.println("Starting readLineWithFinally method.");
    RandomAccessFile in = new RandomAccessFile("products.ran", "r");
    try
    {                     
        String s = in.readLine();
        return s;
    } 
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
                in.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Generic Error Message");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wht is it that you want to achieve??... What is the problem you are facing???

Comment: It might just be working as you expect. If it's a made-up filename, your `System.out.println()` in the `catch` block should return the content of `e`, which very well may be "FileNotFound".

Comment: Are the file names made up as part of your SSCCE, or are you using fake file names when running your code? `FileNotFoundException` is typically thrown when your code cannot find a file. This may be because the path was incorrectly specified, or because the path supplied is incorrect, etc.

Comment: It's an exercise from a book so there isn't a real programming goal other than just teaching me how to work with exceptions. I need it to compile properly and not throw any exceptions (other than the ones I code!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that you posted shouldn't compile, as RandomFile(String, String) can possibly throw `FileNotFoundException`. As such, we must include it in the `try` block.

```
System.out.println("Starting readLineWithFinally method.");
RandomAccessFile in = null;
try {
    in = new RandomAccessFile("products.ran", "r");
    String s = in.readLine();
    return s;
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
    return null;
} finally {
    try {
        if(in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Generic Error Message");
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope... then `in` won't be in scope anymore in the `finally` block and the code won't compile.

Comment: Fixed and edited. Thanks for catching that. Had a bit of a derp moment.

Comment: This works, and I marked it as the correct answer, but what I don't understand is what I did wrong. The book actually tells me specifically to move the "RandomAccessFile in = new RandomAccessFile("products.ran", "r")" outside of the try block (it was originally inside it when I started the exercise). Why did creating the variable outside and assigning null to it, then assigning the new object inside the try statement work?

Comment: @lfernandes As stated in the answer, having `RandomAccessFile(String, String)` outside a `try` block will not compile, as there is a chance that `RandomAccessFile(String, String)` will throw a `FileNotFoundException`. This exception must be handled by your program before the compiler will accept your code. In the code above, we initialise `in` to `null` to preserve scope (so that `in` can be seen in the second `try` block, and then catch any exceptions on the constructor call.

Answer (score 3):

To add on to Taylor Hx's answer, you can take advantage of Java 7's [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) construct to avoid having to use `finally` altogether in your case.

```
public static String readLineWithFinally() {
    System.out.println("Starting readLineWithFinally method.");
    try (RandomAccessFile in = new RandomAccessFile("products.ran", "r")) {
        return in.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        return null;
    }
}
```

You'll also want to be certain that your usage is consistent with [what the API mandates](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#RandomAccessFile%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29) for `RandomAccessFile`.

Comment: This is what I wanted to do, and what I think I would do if I actually had to code something like this in a similar situation. As part of the exercise in the book, it required I use the finally block just to get a grasp on what they do.

Answer (score 0):

> Keep in mind the file name and path are fake but here is what I have:

That is why you will have a `FileNotFoundException` while creating `RandomAccessFile("products.ran", "r")` with read access mode `"r"`.

[From the documentation: `RandomAccessFile(String name, String mode)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#RandomAccessFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

> This constructor throws a `FileNotFoundException` if the mode is
>   `"r"` but the given string does not denote an existing regular file,
>   or if the mode begins with "rw" but the given string does not denote
>   an existing, writable regular file and a new regular file of that name
>   cannot be created, or if some other error occurs while opening or
>   creating the file